# Trying to geocode with geopandas - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Nominatim'

Tags: python, pandas, geocoding, nominatim, geopandas

I'm trying to fix an error I have when I try to use the geocode function in geopandas.

```
from geopandas.geocode import geocode
df['latlong'] = geocode(df.Location, provider="mapquest")
```

This is what I see:

```
/Users/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas-0.1.0.dev_-    py2.7.egg/geopandas/geocode.pyc in geocode(strings, provider, **kwargs)
 72               'mapquest': geopy.geocoders.MapQuest,
 73               'openmapquest': geopy.geocoders.OpenMapQuest,
---> 74               'nominatim' : geopy.geocoders.Nominatim}
 75 
 76     if provider not in coders:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Nominatim'
```

I did try to install the plugin using the instructions here but with no joy: https://github.com/rdeguzman/python-nominatim

Answer (score 3):

Geopandas requires geopy 0.96.3.

You can install it with:

```
pip install geopy==0.96.3
```

Also, using the Mapquest geocoder requires an additional API key argument:

```
df['latlong'] = geocode(df.Location, provider="mapquest", api_key="MAPQUEST_API_KEY")
```